# How to loop through CSV string data of an ACF field and print each value only once?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I know how to print a single value with echo in PHP, but I am stuck when it comes to printing each value in comma separated array one value at a time.

This is what I have:

```
<?php echo wp_kses_post(get_field('field')); ?>
```

where `field` is equal to a predefined single value like `stackof` which I can modify to a CSV string like `stackof, stackog, stackoh, stackoi,...`.

#### This is what I want (from OP's comments):

1. On admin panel, there is a field that I can enter any value. Lets call this value as code. This code is directly printed on the frontend when a button is clicked.
2. I want to print unique and predefined code whenever the button is clicked.
3. To do so, I can enter comma separated codes in the field on admin panel such as CSV string like this `stackof, stackog, stackoh, stackoi,...`. But it will print all the codes on the screen.
4. I need to print each unique codes on the screen one by one when button is clicked. Also, once a code is printed, it shouldn't be printed again.

Note: This loop is not tied to user sessions. So every time any user clicks the button a new code from the CSV field should be printed and older ones should be marked used or discarded.

Comment: is this code is inside some loop? How's you are getting `stackof, stackog, stackoh, stackoi,......`

Comment: Hi @AlivetoDie, in wp admin panel I am able to enter values as I mentioned like `stackof, stackog, stackoh, stackoi,......`. The code is run when a button is clicked.

Comment: ok so `<?php echo wp_kses_post(get_field('field')); ?>` is giving you  `stackof, stackog, stackoh, stackoi,......`? Am i right? If yes what expected outcome you want? Add that in your question pls

Comment: @ArdaUlusoy This is an AdvanceCustomFields code, so I assume you can use `$fields = get_fields( $post_id )` instead. And get all the fields connected to specific post and then just `implode(', ', $fields);` to get the CSV string. [ACF Documentation is here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/)

Comment: It is now bringing whatever value is written in 'field'. What I want is to print each value in the 'field' at a time. Then update the 'field' by deleting printed value.

Comment: You need to expand on your question. What exactly are you trying to do? Is it on admin or on frontend? What [**type of field**](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/#field-types) are we taking about? What do you mean by _whatever value it written in field_ and _each value in the field_, what is the difference?

Comment: @DhavalShah thanks for your help. I am trying to be more clear with my question. 
1. On admin panel, there is a field that I can enter any value. Lets call this value as code. This code is directly printed on the frontend when a button is clicked.
2. I want to print unique and predefined code whenever the button is clicked. 
3. To do so, I can enter comma separated codes in the field on admin panel. But it will print all the codes on the screen. 
4. I need to print each unique codes on the screen one by one when button is clicked. Also, once a code is printed, it shouldn't be printed again

Comment: @ArdaUlusoy And would this printing of code be unique to each user session or it would be effective across the sessions? In other words, if I click the button twice and you visit the same page and click the button would you get the third code value or the first one?

Comment: I am not an ogre.  Improve your question, make it complete, ping me, and I'll consider removing my downvote.

Comment: @DhavalShah it will not be related to user sessions. 
I should get the third one if I click 3 times.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Agreed.  and now you should also vote to close as missing MCVE :)

Comment: FYI, the only way this is possible is either by submitting a form (and refreshing a page), OR by also using javascript.

Comment: @cale_b thanks. I was trying to edit my question but you made it faster and better than I would.

Comment: @cale_b you beat me to it as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

This function should work for you to get the latest code which was never printed. How you call this function is entirely up to you. You can either hook into your ajax code or add new template altogether.

```
<?php
function get_next_val_from_field( $field_name, $post_id = false ){
    // Let's get the field data as string.
    $field_data = get_field( $field_name, $post_id );

    // Did we recieved any data?
    if( ! empty( $field_data) ) {

        // Convert CSV string to an array.
        $field_data = explode( ',', $field_data );

        // Remove any empty values and trim extra spaces from around the values.
        $field_data = array_map( 'trim', array_filter( $field_data ) );

        // Rechecking if array is not empty.
        if( is_array( $field_data ) && ! empty( $field_data) ) {

            // Prefix to know next value inside the string.
            $next_value_prefix = 'mm1707_next--';

            $next_value_found = false;

            // Loop through each value to find next value, if any.
            foreach ($field_data as $key => $value) {
                if ( 0 === strpos( $value, $next_value_prefix ) ) {
                    $next_value         = str_replace( $next_value_prefix, '', $value);
                    $field_data[ $key ] = $next_value;
                    $next_value_found   = true;
                } elseif ( $next_value_found ) {
                    // Now that we have found next value let's mark following
                    // array item as next value and break the loop.
                    $field_data[ $key ] = $next_value_prefix . $value;
                    // No need for further loop now.
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If there wasn't any current value then print first value & mark next one.
            if( empty( $next_value ) ){
                $next_value = $field_data[0];
                $field_data[1] = $next_value_prefix . $field_data[0];
            }
            // Let's update the field inside DB to save currently marked data.
            update_field( $field_name, implode(',', $field_data ), $post_id );

            return $next_value;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Essentially,

1. We are converting CSV string into an array.
2. Then we find the value from the array with `mm1707_next--` prefix,
3. If found then return it, remove the prefix from that value and mark next array value with that prefix.
4. If there is no value with that prefix then let's start from first value.

Comment: thanks. There was 'code1, code2, code3' as `$field_name`. I expected it to return 'code1' first., but it did return nothing.

Comment: `$field_name` is the name/field-key of the AdvanceCustomFields Field. So use above function like, `get_next_val_from_field(  'your_acf_field_key' );` If it is still not returning any data then you are not using this function on a loop or a post page. While ACF tries hard to get the `post_id` to return correct data it may not be possible every time. On such case, you should then explicitly specify the `post_id` parameter for the `get_field()` function.

Comment: It is on a post. When I convert to `get_next_val_from_field('your_acf_field_key' );` the web page is returning error and not opening. The field name when the theme returns code is `'coupon_code'` and it is used with `get_field` function.

Comment: On an other note, can you `var_dump` the return value from `get_field('your_acf_field_key', 'post_id');` and post it back here? So we can see what type of data/object exactly is being returned?.

Comment: When I fill the field with codes like code1, code2, code3, I don't use ' like 'code1', 'code2', 'code3'. Would that be the cause?

Comment: Should I use it like `get_next_val_from_field( 'coupon_code')`, because get_field( 'coupon_code' ) works just fine?

Comment: There was a small bug in my code. I have corrected it so you should not be getting any errors. If `get_field()` is working then my function would work as well. However, my code assumes that the returned data is `comma separated string`. If returned value of `get_field` is something else then above code may throw an error.

Comment: It still did not work. The code returns blank space :) @DhavalShah

Comment: Can you share the `var_dump` of `get_field`? [Per my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196544/how-to-loop-through-csv-string-data-of-an-acf-field-and-print-each-value-only-on/48198251#comment83383643_48198251)

Comment: **code5string(7) "code5"** This is what returns when I take var_dump after `get_field('coupon_code')`. There is only one value in coupon_code field an that is 'code5'.